# How to set control focus in a ASCX user control ?

Tags: asp.net

How to set control focus on Asp.Net user control (ascx file) ?

Comment: Focus is a client side concept while user control is server side. What specifically you need to set focus on?

Comment: Do you want to do this in server code or in JavaScript on clientside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose a property / control from user control.
Access it on parent page and set call .Focus() function.

e.g.

```
((TextBox)userControl.FindControl("TextBox1")).Focus();
```

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint as 'container'. I can't access to the source of the masterpage.

Answer (score 3):

Property example:

CS file for the ASCX:

```
public partial class MyAscxControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    // add a property to the ascx control  
    public WebControl MyTextbox 
    { 
        get
        {
            return txtMyTextbox; // the control's id on your ASCX page
        } 
    }
}
```

CS file for the page that contains the ASCX control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourAscxControlId.MyTextBox.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or just TextBox1.Focus() if you want to use it in control code behind :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want from client side...

```
$("#id").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was the same problem creating an User Control ascx. My original code was in the page and worked properly, but when I cut the code to use it since my User Control, the property SetFocus("...") it's not available to use it in the same way.

```
SetFocus("MyTextBox")
```

I needed to reference the current page to find the TextBox element:

```
MyBase.Page.SetFocus("MyTextBox")
```